# SpriteKit - How to detect which node to affect using tocuch?

Tags: sprite-kit, touch

So i have different kinds of enemies and each kind has multiple enemies appear on the screen, i would like when i touch an enemy i affect it's health, for example an enemy needs to be touched 3 times in order to die(remove from parent). My problem is i don't know what is the best way to detect enemies of the same kind.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if let body = self.nodeAtPoint(location) as? SKSpriteNode {

               if node.name == "enemy1" {
                   //Affect health
               }
               if node.name == "enemy2" {
                   //Affect health

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code i have right now but as you can see it's not right, because "enemy1" will have several nodes with the same name, and giving each of those nodes a specific name is not a practical or efficient way.
So what is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a custom subclass of SKSpriteNode, that would keep track of an enemy's health. Your sprite file might look something like this:

```
class Enemy : SKSpriteNode {
    var health = 3
}
```

And then your condition could look like this:

```
if node.name == "enemy1" {
    (node as Enemy).health--;
}
```

Of course, the example code I gave is over-simplified, but you get the point. If each enemy is represented by it's own class, then the computer can keep track of it individually.

Comment: I'm using a normal class not a SkSpriteNode subclass because that would mess up my code because of it' mandatory initializers. So i' m having hard time converting node as Enemy, because Enemy is not SkSpriteNode.

Comment: It should work the same way if you simply make a subclass of SKNode. The only functionality that is used here is the "name" property, which SKNode has.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 SKNodes "enemies1" "enemies2" "enemies3" that will act as parent nodes, and add them to scene.

Then, instead of adding enemy nodes directly to the scene when you create them, add them as children of the corresponding parent node.

Then, for each enemy, you can check for its parent to see which kind of enemy it is.